# How to show/hide div using input range value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show/hide div using input range value in loop so i need to use this
if someone know im waiting for help

```
$(function() {
    $(".range").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next(".content").toggle();
    });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w1zp3r/1gyxm65o/7/

Comment: So you want to show the content when the range indicator is past halfway?

Comment: What exactly you need to do with range selector? I mean does the div will display at a certain value on range or just the click?

Comment: @CataJohn hmm , yes somehow i wanted to show div when exact value selected

Comment: @CodingMaster I want to show div when .. for example: customer choose a value under value 3 a div appear and ask why did you choose 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figured it out

if someone else need can use this

```
$(function() {
$(".range").on('click', function() {
if ($("input").val() == 5 ) {

      $(this).parent().next(".content").toggle();
  }
  else {
    $(this).parent().next(".content").hide();
  }
});
```

})

Comment: You should use `.on('change')` instead of click. This will get the value even if the user holds the click button while changing the range. Also if `$('input')` refers to `.range` you should use `this.value` instead. In your case you are checking the value of all `inputs` in your app.